# Host SharePoint provider-hosted apps on SharePoint farm's WFE servers

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I have a SharePoint 2013 farm deployed in my company (5 WFEs). I'd like to build SharePoint provider-hosted apps for that farm. In order to do that I need to have another Windows farm (which I'm not going to get) to host those provider-hosted apps.
My idea is to host SharePoint provider-hosted apps on the existing WFEs (to overcome this situation).

What possible drawbacks could you imagine if I followed that idea?